# Bounding box annotation in Pascal VOC format

Tags: amazon-web-services, bounding-box

I would like to do object detection in Tensorflow using Faster-RCNN method.

I am planning to use Amazon Mechanical Turk crowdsourcing for obtaining the annotations. However, does anyone know if there is any bounding box annotation tools out there that supports mturk and outputs the annotation in xml file in Pascal VOC format.